# Express: How to wait for a function to complete before calling something

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having an issue in Express. The following piece of code finds all the value in the pokemon collection and one by one, checks another collection to find matches. However, the code reaches `res.send(documents)` before all the items are finished inserting (`display.insert(docs)`). I know this is because of the way node works asynchronously, but I can't find a way to get past this issue. How can I ensure all of the documents get inserted?

```
pokeRouter.get('/sightings/:type([a-z]+)', function(req, res) {
display.deleteMany({}, function(err, bool) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (bool) {
        pokemon.find().each(function(err, item) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (item == null) {
                display.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    res.send(documents);
                })
            } else if ((req.params.type == item.type1) || (req.params.type == item.type2)) {
                sightings.find({
                    pokedex_id: item._id
                }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                    if (docs == null) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        display.insert(docs);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: There are hundreds of dups of this issue.  Some of your operations are asynchronous.  That means they won't be done until sometime later (only in their callback), but your code assumes they are done immediately and thus tries to be done before the async operations are done.  You cannot make anything wait.  Instead, you have to code for async results by continuing your processing IN the completion callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `display.insert(...)` function is probably also async. So the function inside the `find().each(...)` is returning before the insert is finished.

I highly recommend converting your the callbacks to Promises or use the async module to handle your async stuff.

Answer (score 0):

without using Promises or async module, you can refactor your code to have documents variable outside the async code and accumulate all the insertable items, and in your async code you would have some type of check (if everything is inserted) then I would call res.send(documents)